# Jupyter Notebook Launch Error: _update_save_script() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I created a new environment in Anaconda, and got the error while starting Jupyter. Can anybody help?

> Jupyter Notebook Launch Error: _update_save_script() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

[image]

Comment: Better to type the text of the error message in the body of the question, than to just post an image.

Comment: I created a new jupyter_notebook_config.py to overwrite the old. And problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter notebooks depend on the BROWSER environment variable. You can unset the browser typing "unset BROWSER" in the terminal to fix this error.